# Please help me with this doubt from waves

Tags: waves, acoustics

what is phase difference and how to visualize it?
i am able to understand it pretty well in sinusoidal waves but please tell me what it is in other type of waves like plane waves,spherical waves,etc.

Comment: When you say "sinusoidal waves" I assume you mean in shape, like a wave on the surface of water? Plane and spherical waves can have a sinusoidal *intensity* profile, which is analogous to the sinusoidal *height* profile of a water wave.

Comment: but sir,what is the physical significance of phase difference?

Comment: for example A means the maximum displacement of the particle,T means the time after which the wave pattern repeats,wavelength is the length after which wave pattern repeats,so what is the physical significance of phase difference?or what is the definition of phase difference?

Comment: my textbook often contains statements like" these 2 waves have constant phase difference"(most refers to spherical sound waves),but iam unable to visualize it,what does it mean?please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I think you'll find all the details you need at [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232028/what-is-the-difference-in-the-uses-of-omega-t-and-kx-in-wave-equation).

As Asher commented,  when a wave is described as sinusoidal, or triangular, or square, that's its amplitude profile.   When a wave is described as plane or spherical,  that's the spatial profile perpendicular to the direction of propagation.  For example,  a plane wave of sinusoidal amplitude will have the same phase, i.e. amplitude at all $(x,y)$ coordinates for a given $z$ (direction of propagation).  If the amplitude is maximum at $z_0$, then the amplitude will be a peak at $z_1$ which is one-quarter wavelength away.

Similarly, for a spherical wave, the phase is the same on all points on a spherical surface (common radius from the origin).

Comment: thank you for replying sir,but i want to know the physical significance of phase difference,for example A means the maximum displacement of the particle,T means the time after which the wave pattern repeats,wavelength is the length after which wave pattern repeats,so what is the physical significance of phase difference?or what is the definition of phase difference?

Comment: my textbook often contains statements like "these 2 waves have constant phase difference"(most refers to spherical sound waves),but iam unable to visualize it,what does it mean?please help

Comment: "Constant phase difference" suggests they have the same wavelength and propagation speed, so they can be parametrized as $A_1 = sin(kt+\phi_1)$  and $A_2=sin(kt+\phi_2)$ . If you graph the two waveforms and shift one waveform by the relative phase difference, the peaks and valleys will be in the same locations.

Comment: sir,i understand it know,but how do you explain it from the wavefront perspective?

Comment: please explain phase difference for this example,when you dip 2 fingers in water simultaneously two spherical waves are produced and they interfere,now how to tell whether they are in phase or not since they don;t look like sinusoidal?pleas help.