# How to understand motion of waves through functions of two variables - time and distance?

Tags: waves, kinematics, oscillators, vibrations

$$ s(x,t)= A \sin(\frac{2\pi}{T}t-\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x) $$

Basically I would love to get some plausible and thorough explanation of plotting these two independent variables in order to satisfy the harmonic motion of waves.

Comment: You can plot $s$ against $x$ for several values of $t$. You can plot $s$ against $t$ for several values of $x$. You can make a 3D plot of $s$ above a $t$-$x$ plane. I recommend the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you are moving with the wave. The amplitude of the wave is then constant in that frame. The wave has a constant phase 
$$
\theta=\frac{2\pi}{T}t-\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}x,
$$
so that $d\theta/dt=0$ which leads to
$$
0=\frac{2\pi}{T}-\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\frac{dx}{dt}.
$$
This means the velocity is $v=\lambda/T$ and for frequency $\nu=1/T$ we get the standard formula $v=\lambda\nu$.

Comment: Related [What is the difference in the uses of ωt and kx in wave equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232028/what-is-the-difference-in-the-uses-of-omega-t-and-kx-in-wave-equation/232039#232039)

Comment: It is in the SE page you cited. $\omega=2\pi/T$ and $k=2\pi/\lambda$.